# Term for non-exposure-related tolerance?

Tags: medications, alcohol, terminology, drug-metabolism

"Tolerance" to a drug is typically interpreted to mean the state of requiring more of that drug to cause the same effects as compared to another individual, regardless of cause. However, the medical profession recognizes tolerance only in so far as it refers to the exposure-related sense. So while a college student who rarely drinks and yet due to genetics requires a large amount of alcohol to become inebriated might be said to have "tolerance" by other college students, a doctor would say that only the effects of exposure to alcohol can be considered true tolerance.

Is there a term for "natural" tolerance, unrelated to exposure to a substance?

Comment: Hmm I wonder if this belongs to linguistics.se or something? It's mainly about the language rather than health, but I wouldn't mind keeping a question like this on health.se, since it certainly does pertain to health.